# Absorption coefficient from HITEMP or HITRAN

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy, absorption

How to calculate the absorption coefficient (for radiation) from [HITEMP](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=hitemp+database) or [HITRAN](http://www.cfa.harvard.edu/hitran/) databases?

Or where can I find some tables or plots for the absorption coefficient?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific.  The absorption cross-sections reported in these databases are determined empirically and vary by temperature and molecule.  If you want a plot or table you should mention which molecule, temperature regime, and wavelength region you are interested in.

Comment: @farrenthorpe I need at least some examples of tables for some temperatures and infrared wavelengths, for example, for air or another gases.

Comment: air is a mixture... i wouldn't think "air" is in the Hitran database.   there are also different entries depending on the author/researcher.  Here check out this link: http://vpl.astro.washington.edu/spectra/o3.htm

Comment: @farrenthorpe Thank you. What data is plotted on the page "Images of HITRAN data"?
How to obtain the absorption coefficient (measured in cm$^{-1}$)?

Comment: Absorption coefficients are in square centimeters not inverse centimeters.  I'm not sure if I understand your question but the "Images of HITRAN data" is showing the cross-sectional absorption area of ozone.. the units on the y-axis are square centimeters ("Sigma" aka the absorption coefficient) while the x-axis is inverse wavelength in wavenumbers (aka inverse centimeters).  It says "Absorption cross sections recorded with a high-resolution Fourier-transform spectrometer at 293K and 100 mbar, between 230 and 830 nm"

Comment: @farrenthorpe http://vpl.astro.washington.edu/spectra/co2.htm -- this page contains information that units for Images of HITRAN data is cm/molecule, not cm$^2$.
Is it absorption cross-section? I need data for the absorption coefficient which is inverse to mean free path and measured in cm$^{-1}$.

Comment: Are you talking about the attenuation coefficient, which is in inverse centimeters?  Or just the absorption portion (no scattering) of the attenuation?  The HITRAN data I pointed to is in square centimeters per molecule which is how absorption is quantified in the lab.  I suggest you look at the wikipedia pages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law ... I've never studied Beer's Lambert law using an "absorption coefficient" but apparently it's just the cross section times number of molecules in the path.

Comment: @farrenthorpe Since there are cm/molecule for HITRAN data on the page http://vpl.astro.washington.edu/spectra/co2.htm, I think that this is spectral line intensity, isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes I hadn't noticed those images further down.  I think you are right.  I see "The units for intensity in HITRAN are cm-1/( molecule × cm-2 ) at the standard HITRAN temperature of 296 K. " stated here: http://www.cfa.harvard.edu/hitran/FAQ.html

Comment: The HITRAN "intensity" parameter for each spectral line can be converted into an absorption cross-section as a function of wavelength. (For example code showing how to do this conversion, see https://github.com/nzhagen/hitran) Using Beer's law you can then take the given cross-section of a gas, select a wavelength, and calculate the absorption for a given gas concentration and path length through the gas.